# Stripe.createPaymentMethod Causes App to Freeze on Android and Stops Further Execution

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates, flutter-stripe

I'm using [flutter_stripe](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe) package and I have functionality in my app to save a card, so it can be used later. I'm following these steps;

1. Calling Stripe.instance.createPaymentMethod
2. Calling Stripe.instance.createToken
3. Posting the Token received in step 2 to RestAPI.

> Logs suggest that my app takes a lot of time to process steps 1 and
> causes jank and once that is done, the app halts the execution of the
> rest of the steps.

**Step 1**

```
await Stripe.instance.createPaymentMethod(
        params: PaymentMethodParams.card(
          paymentMethodData: PaymentMethodData(
            billingDetails:
                BillingDetails(name: cardHolderName), // it didn't work
          ),
        ),
        options: const PaymentMethodOptions(
            setupFutureUsage: PaymentIntentsFutureUsage.OnSession));
```

Step 2, 3

```
  await Stripe.instance
        .createToken(const CreateTokenParams.card(
            params: CardTokenParams(
      type: TokenType.Card,
    
         ))).then((value) async {
    
      print('Token Received');

      // Calling API
      await createCard(value.id);
    
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
     getErrorDialog(error);
    });
  }
```

**Logs** (During the execution of this function)

```
I/flutter (18568): Started Execution
I/ViewRootImpl(18568): jank_removeInvalidNode jank list is null
I/ViewRootImpl(18568): jank_removeInvalidNode jank list is null
I/ViewRootImpl(18568): jank_removeInvalidNode jank list is null
I/ViewRootImpl(18568): jank_removeInvalidNode jank list is null
I/ViewRootImpl(18568): jank_removeInvalidNode jank list is null
I/ViewRootImpl(18568): jank_removeInvalidNode jank list is null
I/ViewRootImpl(18568): jank_removeInvalidNode jank list is null
I/flutter (18568): Pay Method Created
I/Choreographer(18568): Skipped 73 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/ViewRootImpl(18568): jank_removeInvalidNode jank list is null
I/ViewRootImpl(18568): jank_removeInvalidNode jank list is null
E/flutter ( 1627): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
E/flutter ( 1627): #0      _$$_TokenDataFromJson (package:stripe_platform_interface/src/models/create_token_data.g.dart:146:40)
E/flutter ( 1627): #1      new _$_TokenData.fromJson (package:stripe_platform_interface/src/models/create_token_data.freezed.dart:1777:7)
E/flutter ( 1627): #2      _$TokenDataFromJson (package:stripe_platform_interface/src/models/create_token_data.freezed.dart:1577:21)
E/flutter ( 1627): #3      new TokenData.fromJson (package:stripe_platform_interface/src/models/create_token_data.dart:144:7)
E/flutter ( 1627): #4      MethodChannelStripe.createToken.<anonymous closure> (package:stripe_platform_interface/src/method_channel_stripe.dart:287:44)
E/flutter ( 1627): #5      ResultParser.parse (package:stripe_platform_interface/src/result_parser.dart:14:24)
E/flutter ( 1627): #6      MethodChannelStripe.createToken (package:stripe_platform_interface/src/method_channel_stripe.dart:288:10)
E/flutter ( 1627): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1627): #7      Stripe.createToken (package:flutter_stripe/src/stripe.dart:286:25)
E/flutter ( 1627): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1627): #8      FutureExtensions.onError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:1049:15)
E/flutter ( 1627): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1627):
```

This problem occurrs only on Android.

I tried using `Isolates` but it didn't affect the performance, probably because I couldn't configure it well. So any guide on using Isolates for my case would be helpful (Please don't share medium articles, as I've already seen some).

### On Using compute I get the Stripe config error

```
Unhandled Exception: Instance of 'StripeConfigException'
```

Then, to bypass this error I set the `Stripe.pusblishKey` again in my function that is called by `compute`, and I got this error and the recommended solutions to this did not work for me.

```
Unhandled Exception: Bad state: The BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.instance value is invalid until BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized is executed.
E/flutter (29872): #0   BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.instance (package:flutter/src/services/_background_isolate_binary_messenger_io.dart:27:7)
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

From the logs you posted, the error originates from the `flutter_stripe` library's handling of the token response from the Stripe API:

```
E/flutter ( 1627): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
E/flutter ( 1627): #0      _$$_TokenDataFromJson (package:stripe_platform_interface/src/models/create_token_data.g.dart:146:40)
```

This indicates that when the `flutter_stripe` library is trying to parse the response from the Stripe API into its internal model, it's running into a type conflict: an `int` value is being provided where a `String` is expected.

It's hard to diagnose the exact cause without more context, but a few possible solutions come to mind:

1. Verify if the parameters you're providing to the 'createToken' method are correct.
2. **Check your Stripe API version**: Make sure the version of the Stripe API you're using is compatible with the version of the `flutter_stripe` library in your project. There might be a discrepancy between the data types used in the API response and what the library is expecting.
3. **Upgrade or downgrade `flutter_stripe`**: If the problem is in the library, it's possible that either upgrading to a newer version or downgrading to an older, stable version might solve the problem. Be sure to check the changelogs and see if this is a known issue that has been resolved in a different version.
4. **Report the issue to the `flutter_stripe` team**: If you've ensured your API version and library version are compatible and you're still experiencing the issue, it might be a bug in the library. You can open an issue in the GitHub repository for the `flutter_stripe` library. Be sure to include the error log, the version of the library you're using, and the version of the Stripe API your server is using.

In the meantime, if you have control over the server code, you could use a workaround. Instead of creating a token on the client side, you could send the card data directly to your server and create the token there using Stripe's official libraries. This has the added advantage of keeping your sensitive card handling logic on the server side. However, make sure to follow Stripe's best practices for handling sensitive data to keep your user's data secure.

About the jank and frame-skipping issue, Flutter applications are single-threaded, and all the work is done on the UI thread. So, if a task takes too long, you will see a warning about skipped frames. In your case, it seems the operation of creating a token is taking too long and causing the application to skip frames, creating jank.

You tried using Isolates, but please note that due to the architectural design of Flutter and Dart, isolates can't share memory, meaning you can't access variables or objects from the main thread in another isolate. This might be why you didn't notice any improvement when using isolates.

However, it's important to note that network requests, like the ones to Stripe, are inherently asynchronous and don't block the UI thread, so they shouldn't be causing jank. If you're experiencing jank, it might be caused by something else in your code, like heavy computation or complex UI rendering.

Comment: The parsing issue was resolved in the latest build of `flutter_stripe`.